# Rails brakeman warning of sql injection

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-injection, brakeman

I've got a scope in my model :

```
scope :assigned_to_user, ->(user) {
task_table = UserTask.table_name

    joins("INNER JOIN #{task_table}
          ON  #{task_table}.user_id = #{user.id}
          AND (#{task_table}.type_id = #{table_name}.type_id)
          AND (#{task_table}.manager_id = #{table_name}.manager_id)
        ")
}
```

So after running brakeman report I get this warning :

```
assigned_to_user | SQL Injection | Possible
```

So I tried the following :

```
scope :assigned_to_user, ->(user) {
    task_table = UserTask.table_name

        joins(ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize("INNER JOIN #{task_table}
              ON  #{task_table}.user_id = #{user.id}
              AND (#{task_table}.type_id = #{table_name}.type_id)
              AND (#{task_table}.manager_id = #{table_name}.manager_id)
            "))
    }
```

This doesn't work for me because it adds `'` (apostrophe) to the front and back of the sql. So when I use this as a part of query which returns some results and I apply this scope it generates the incorrect sql.

I also tried this:

```
scope :assigned_to_user, ->(user) {
    task_table = UserTask.table_name

        joins("INNER JOIN #{task_table}
              ON  #{task_table}.user_id = ?
              AND (#{task_table}.type_id = #{table_name}.type_id)
              AND (#{task_table}.manager_id = #{table_name}.manager_id)
            ", user.id)
    }
```

Doesn't even build the statement. And tried couple of other stuff which didn't work and not even worth mentioning. Does anybody have idea how to fix this?

Comment: While it is always good to sanitize values per the selected answer, Brakeman warning in this case is a false positive that will be fixed with https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/pull/634

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some kind of research here is what I would use.
There is a method called `sanitize_sql_array` ([ref](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods/sanitize_sql_array)), you can use it to escape statements by passing an sql string and replacement values to it like:

```
sanitize_sql_array(['user_id = :user_id', user_id: 5])
# => "user_id = 5"
```

If we'd pass a table name to this method it will also escape it, but will apply a `quote` method of `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` object on a value, which is used to escape variables, but not table names. Maybe sometimes it will work, but it failed for me when I was using PostrgreSQL, because `quote` method uses single quotes, but PostgreSQL requires double-quotation for table names.

```
sanitize_sql_array([
  'INNER JOIN :table_name ON :table_name.user_id = :user_id',
  { table_name: 'users', user_id: 5 }
])
# => "INNER JOIN 'users' ON 'users'.user_id = 5"
```

`connection` object also has a method `quote_table_name`, which could be separately applied on table names, to make sure that they are escaped + use `sanitize_sql_array` for user id.

```
scope :assigned_to_user, -> (user) {
  task_table = connection.quote_table_name(UserTask.table_name)
  current_table = connection.quote_table_name(table_name)
  sanitized_sql = sanitize_sql_array([
    "INNER JOIN #{task_table}
    ON  #{task_table}.user_id = :user_id
    AND (#{task_table}.type_id = #{current_table}.type_id)
    AND (#{task_table}.manager_id = #{current_table}.manager_id)",
    { user_id: user.id }
  ])
  joins(sanitized_sql)
}
```

Or you could actually just use `sanitize` on `user.id` instead of wrapping everything in `sanitize_sql_array` method call (`#{sanitize(user.id)}`).

By the way, Brakeman won't already show any warnings, because query has been moved to a variable. Brakeman literally parses your code as is and it does not know about a variable and it's content. So all this thing is just to make yourself sure that everything is being escaped.

Just to shut up Brakeman you could just move a query to a variable:

```
scope :assigned_to_user, -> (user) {
  task_table = UserTask.table_name
  query = "INNER JOIN #{task_table}
          ON  #{task_table}.user_id = #{user.id}
          AND (#{task_table}.type_id = #{table_name}.type_id)
          AND (#{task_table}.manager_id = #{table_name}.manager_id)"
  joins(query)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your research. All others worked except the last one. The brakeman still detected that one. However if you store the string inside ``%Q{..query here..}`` that bypasses the warning.