# Sanitizing a Stored Procedure Call in SQL Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, stored-procedures, activerecord

I'm working in Rails, ActiveRecord, and Postgresql, and am attempting to sanitize a SQL statement that executes a stored procedure:

```
query =<<-SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM #{stored_procedure_name}
    (
        #{param_1},
        #{param_2}
    )
SQL
```

The above statement works when executed. From what I understand, the stored procedure should be sanitized at the database layer because of parametrization (due to the way I defined the function). However, how can I sanitize the `query` above? I tried ActiveRecord's `sanitize` methods to no avail by using something like

```
statement =<<-SQL
    SELECT * FROM ? (?, ?)
SQL
```

and then passing the parameters in, but this didn't work - and seems silly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done this:

1. Create the string query just like you did, but replace the `?` with named parameters, like this:

   ```
   statement = <<-SQL
   SELECT * FROM :procedure_name (:param_1, :param_2)
   SQL
   ```
2. Now call your query like this:

   ```
   YourModel.find_by_sql([
     statement,
     {
       procedure_name: 'your_procedure_name',
       param_1: 'your param 1 value',
       param_2: 'your second param value'
     }
   ])
   ```

This has worked for me to execute complex select queries, I haven't tried it for stored procedures, but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately this throws an error `SELECT * FROM 'procedure_name'` because the function name is wrapped in single quotes

Comment: makes sense, let me see if I can find a way to fix that.

Comment: No, you can't fix this, the procedure name cannot be a parameter to the query.

Comment: I forgot something about stored procedures in mysql, you should call them with `CALL`.

Comment: @fanta , this is in postgresql, should have clarified, my apologies

Comment: I see, so, to call a function in postgres you need to remove the `*`, I don't know if that's going to work though. And also remove the space between the function name and the parenthesis ?.

Comment: @fibono, you can do what this guy did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853371/rails-brakeman-warning-of-sql-injection

Comment: @fanta, yes, I actually ended up doing that. Also, the function name was stored in the db, so it's not passed in the params.Thank you!